# How to load a Page based on local storage value, in Ionic With Angular

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I want to show RegisterPage, based on the result of, if condition inside the constructor. I’m new to Ionic and Angular. Can anyone suggest me to do this requirement.

**app.component.ts**

```
  export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;
    rootPage:any = RegisterPage; 
    constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      if(localStorage["User"]||localStorage["Tenant"]===null){      
      this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);             //call reg form
      }
        else{
        //call login form        
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-nav #mainContent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
          if(localStorage["User"]||localStorage["Tenant"]===null)
           {
            this.rootPage = RegisterPage; 
          }
          else{
            this.rootPage = LoginPage;
         }
 });
```

Try this